# Is it possible to manipulate Python's syntax with something like macros (like Nim's)?

Tags: python, syntax, macros, abstract-syntax-tree, nim-lang

While programing in Nim, I came across macros and was surprised at how expressive they were—you could basically add new syntax! I've looked hard and long to see if I could do something like that in Python, but couldn't find anything.

Is it possible to add new syntax to python? If so, how would it be done? With the `ast` module, perhaps?

**Example:**

let_macro.py:

```py
import ast
# something like this
ast.new_macro(
    ast.expect("let"),
    ast.expect(ast.ident(store_as="name")),
    ast.expect("="),
    ast.expect(ast.expr, store_as="expr"),
    replace_with="{name} = {expr}"
)
```

and usage would be like:

```py
import let_macro
let x = 12 # replace with x = 12
```

Comment: You might want to look into how ren'py implements its scripting language. That sort of thing is probably the best you can do; Python won't start natively recognizing your extended language, but with enough effort it should be possible to make it bytecode-compile.